# What is the standard way to create a checkbox programmatically in Swift 4.0 using Cocoa?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa

I've been asked to update an existing macOS program, and have been given an Xcode project written in Swift 4.0. The program uses Cocoa to generate the interface programmatically.

I haven't used Swift (or Xcode) before and am unfamiliar with Cocoa, so I'm trying to pick it up as I go, but I was able to add a button to the interface with the following code:

```
public lazy var phaseInvertButton: NSButton = {
    let button = NSButton()
    self.addSubview(button)
    return button
}()
```

However, when I tried to add a checkbox using the same code and an additional line,
`button.setButtonType(NSSwitchButton)`, I got an error:

`'NSSwitchButton' is unavailable in Swift.`

I also tried creating it with
`public lazy var phaseInvertButton: NSSwitchButton`, but got the same error. According to the Cocoa documentation, NSSwitchButton is a subtype of NSButton, but I can't seem to get it working in Swift.

Can anyone enlighten me as to how I should create a checkbox programmatically in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
let button = NSButton(checkboxWithTitle:"Title" target:nil action:nil)
```

If you want to stick with setting the button type of an `NSButton`, the type you want is [`.switch`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsbutton/buttontype):

```
button.setButtonType(.switch)
```